# How to optimize SQL query without losing data?

Tags: mysql, sqlperformance

I am working with MySQL to query database tables.

I finally find that the following query returns what I want from my database. ( I am not SQL expert)

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT swtickets.ticketid, swtickets.ticketstatustitle, swtickets.departmenttitle, swtickets.subject, swtickets.dateline, swtickets.ownerstaffname, swtickets.lastreplier, swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue, swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid FROM swtickets, swcustomfieldvalues WHERE swcustomfieldvalues.typeid=swtickets.ticketid AND swtickets.ticketid IN (SELECT typeid FROM `swcustomfieldvalues` WHERE `fieldvalue`=12345678)) as tbl
where tbl.customfieldid=123
```

However, the above query is taking a long time to show results in phpMyAdmin.

```
Showing rows 0 - 24 (32 total, Query took 7.1488 sec)
```

Can this query be optimized to be faster than 7 seconds?

Here is my SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3b5a2

**More explanation:**

Table: `swcustomfieldvalues`

```
customfieldvalueid
customfieldid
typeid <— This field is not unique in this table
fieldvalue
isserialized
isencrypted
dateline
uniquehash
lastupdated
```

For each ticket, I have 9 custom fields in `swcustomfieldvalues`
All 9 custom fields for each ticket have SAME `typeid` (= `ticketid` in `swtickes` table).

If `customfieldid` = 6, then `fieldvalue` holds user full name

If `customfieldid` = 7, then `fieldvalue` holds user mobile number

If I query this table for `typeid=98765`

I will get 9 rows all have SAME typeid and different values for `fieldvalue` and `customfieldid` etc…

I want from this result (the 9 rows) the `fieldvalue` value where `customfieldid=6` but only if the `fieldvalue=1234567` where `customfieldid=7`

I already have this value `1234567` in my query, so I do not care if it is listed in the result or not.

**More explanation:**

[image]

All current answers successfully fetch these set of rows for each ticket that has mobile number as provided in the query PLUS other ticket derails from ‘swtickets’ table.

What are we doing so far:
The search (query) is performed with condition on the when customfieldid=7 and fieldvalue = 0555.

Everything is fine. But I do not want field value to appear on result (I do not care about it) I want the name to appear on my result of rows.

I want the `fieldvalue` for the row that has `customfieldid=6` only if:

the row with `customfieldid=7` has `fieldvalue=0555`

**Results of two queries (Mine and the on on answers'):**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it simple by using something like this,

```
SELECT 
swtickets.ticketid, 
swtickets.ticketstatustitle, 
swtickets.departmenttitle, 
swtickets.subject, 
swtickets.dateline, 
swtickets.ownerstaffname, 
swtickets.lastreplier, 
swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue,
swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid 
FROM swtickets
LEFT JOIN swcustomfieldvalues 
ON 
swcustomfieldvalues.typeid = swtickets.ticketid 
AND
swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue = 12345678 
AND
swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid = 123
```

Comment: I am getting error: `Not unique table/alias: 'swcustomfieldvalues' `

Comment: Almost correct except it returns for me unwanted `swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue` for `swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid` not equals `123`

Comment: Please see my added explanation

Comment: @MIH1406 Can you please check again,

Comment: Please see updated questions with result screenshots for both queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select swtickets.ticketid, swtickets.ticketstatustitle, swtickets.departmenttitle, swtickets.subject, swtickets.dateline, swtickets.ownerstaffname, swtickets.lastreplier, swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue, swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid
      from swtickets
      join swcustomfieldvalues ON (swtickets.ticketid = swcustomfieldvalues.typeid)
      where swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue = 12345678 and swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid=123
```

Comment: same result as other answers.

Comment: All answers fetch correct number of rows but the data from `swcustomfieldvalues` are not what I want.

Comment: I want from that table the value of column `fieldvalue` where `customfieldid` is 6. But on querying, I want to match `fieldvalue` when `customfieldid` is 7

Comment: Please see updated questions with result screenshots for both queries.